# mscorlib.dll is messing up my TFS gated build

Tags: c#, tfs, build, msbuild, mscorlib

I recently upgraded my TFS from 2013 to 2015 and also I had a fresh Windows Server 2012R2. Everything is working fine except when I check in it is failing. I have a gated build setup, so tries to build on the server.

> An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been
>   imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

After a bit googling, people saying remove the mscorlib.dll from bin folder and that fixes it, but I didn't put it in manually, so how do I remove it?

Has anyone else faced the same issue? What should I do fix it?

**UPDATE:**

One of my projects in the solution had a different framework target and I just changed it, that made the error go away.

Comment: The build server is on the fresh Windows Server 2012R2?

Comment: Is the build server on the same server as TFS?